# "pyautogui" doesn't respond

Tags: python, input, mouseevent, pyautogui

I wrote a small code with python. But this part of the code doesn't work when game focused on and it doesnt respond back.

`pyautogui.moveRel(-2, 4)`

Also this part works when my cursor appear in menu or etc. too. But when i switched into game (when my cursor disappear and crosshair appeared) it doesn't work (doesn't matter fullscreen or else). These type of keyboard commands are in my code also but they works fine.

`keyboard.is_pressed('Alt')`

It's about mouse or pyautogui ?.. How can i make mouse moves correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code below:

`import win32con`

`import win32api`

`win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(10), int(10), 0, 0)`

And it worked in game. I think it relative with win32con. Anyway i got it.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem in linux. For me it was wayland. After switching to X, it worked. In `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` uncomment the line `#WaylandEnable=false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how PyAutoGui works:

```
0,0       X increases -->
+---------------------------+
|                           | Y increases
|                           |     |
|   1920 x 1080 screen      |     |
|                           |     V
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+ 1919, 1079
```

So you need to write like this:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200
```

or

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200, 2)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200 over 2 seconds
```

Comment: But it works on other stuffs except games. Why doesn't work it in games? And my purpose is that moving the mouse with pixels, not coordinates. If there is an another way to do what i want, please share with me.

Comment: Because games are in the fullscreen resolution. Try this: `pyautogui.press('esc')` and then move mouse

Comment: This command doesn't work either and none(pyautogui commands) doesn't work in windowed/fullscreen mode.

Comment: @ChaTho Does the game require directX input?